# Editing C files generated from lex and bison files

Tags: c, compiler-warnings, bison, lex

I have been in trouble of removing warning from `.c` files which are generated by 
`.l(lex)` and `.y(bison)`. I don't have any compiler warning in `lex` and `bison` files. But I get following type of warning in the generated `C` file.

```
 parser.c:1772:34: warning: conversion to 'long unsigned int' from 'long int' may change the sign of the result
```

This is the warning from the `parser.c`. This parser.c is generated from `parser.y`. Could you please let me know how can i permanently remove those warning as editing in the parser.c does not make any sense for next compilation.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might get better answers if you explained what you wanted changed in those files and why. Whenever possible the right thing with generated code is to *improve the generation* rather than diddling the results by hand.

Comment: Code generated by lex and yacc tends to be a bit hairy (after all it's doing some pretty complicated stuff) so I wouldn't bother - or is there a no-exceptions 0 warnings policy in place without exception for tool-generated sources?

Answer (score 2):

If the warning is related to generated part of the bison/lex code (not your action).
Probably the only solution is to modify the skeleton.

But most likely the warning is related to the action part in your bison/lex source code, you simply have to modify the action. Keep in mind that bison does not analyze the content of your action (ie. all the code inside braces.

Suppose that your are using a function returning an  `unsigned int` and that use it in one action like that :

```
  rule : foo { $$ = some_function_returning_an_unsigned_int($1); }
              ^-------------------------------------------------^
                here : bison only expand the $'s to the correct c expression
```

If the expected token type for rule is an int you will have a c warning.

Without the source line (1772:34) and the context it is hard to give a precise answer to your question.

Answer (score 1):

Your Flex/Lex and Bison/Yacc files will tell me more about this problem. The reason why Flex and Bison don't give you warnings when they are generating the code is because they treat your code as a block of text and don't attempt to make sense of it. That is the C compilers job.

The c code is generated from your files. It is not a good idea to tweek the generated code since it is fairly complex. Much better to get it right at the source.